# How to display image from custom post type in a page with a post object field?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have two ACF fields, one for custom post type (image field) and the other one (Post Object field) for a page. See https://share.getcloudapp.com/ApuLkGEp

Then I created a plugin using a shortcode to pull those items but I'm not able to get the image from the custom post type to display it in the page.

Below is my code:

```
if( have_rows('select_team_member') ):
// Loop through rows.
while( have_rows('select_team_member') ) : the_row();
    
    // check for rows (sub repeater)
    if( have_rows('set') ): ?>
        <div class="staff-feature">
        <?php 
        // loop through rows (sub repeater)
        while( have_rows('set') ): the_row();
            $member = get_sub_field('member');
            $image = get_field_object('field_59081633e8de4', $member->ID);
            $size = 'full';
            $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
            ?>
            <div class="set">
                <div class="staff-pop-wrap">                    
                    <?php var_dump( $thumbnail ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; //if( get_sub_field('items') ): 

// End loop.
endwhile;
```

endif;

I want to display the bio_portrait image field but it gives me this value: https://share.getcloudapp.com/RBuWO9n5

Comment: Can u check if the $image variable you are passing in wp_get_attachment_image function is the correct id of the image u want?

Answer (score 0):

`get_field_object` returns an array of settings and the value.

you could use `$image['value']` to actually get the value (which might be an object, array or ID according to your return settings).

But you could also just use the normal `get_field/get_sub_field` methods for images as well..

You will see it, if you were to `var_dump($image)` for debugging.